# Recursively need to search and remove using python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm tying to run below python code to remove the `User-ID` if it exists in the text files present inside and its sub-directories of `/home/user/excel/report/` directory recursively. However getting below mentioned error. I'm new to python not sure whether below code can handle recursively, Therefore need help to solve this.  Thanks in advance for the help.

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
d = dict(zip(data["File Name"], data["User-ID"]))

for file in d:
    with open("f /home/user/excel/report/{file}.txt", "r") as f:
        contents = f.read().strip()
    
    with open("f /home/user/excel/report/{file}.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(contents.replace(d[file], ""))
```

```
$ python script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 8, in <module>
    with open("f /home/user/excel/report/{file}.txt", "r") as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'f /home/user/excel/report/{file}.txt'
```

Folder tree structure of `/home/user/excel/report` given below.

```
├── JEBER
│   ├── B1298
│   │   ├── file01.txt
│   │   └── file02.txt
│   ├── BookMark
│   │   ├── mark01.txt
│   │   └── mark02.txt
│   ├── Loader
│   │   ├── BlueRay
│   │   │   ├── 23550
│   │   │   │   ├── R2501.txt
│   │   │   │   ├── R2502.txt
│   │   │   │   └── Mark01.txt
```

Updated code-1:-

```py
import os
import subprocess
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
d = dict(zip(data["File Name"], data["User-ID"]))


for file in d:
    find_cmd = 'find /home/user/excel/reports -name -name "{0}"'.format(file)
    full_path = subprocess.check_output(find_cmd, shell=True).split()[0]
    
    with open(f"/home/user/excel/reports/{file}.txt", "r") as f:
        contents = f.read().strip()
    
    with open(f"/home/user/excel/reports/{file}.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(contents.replace(d[file], ""))
```

Error:

```
$ python3.6 script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 11, in <module>
    full_path = subprocess.check_output(find_cmd, shell=True).split()[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Updated code-2:-

```py
import os
import subprocess
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
d = dict(zip(data["File Name"], data["User-ID"]))


for dname, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/user/excel/report/"):
    for fname in files:
        fpath = os.path.join(dname, fname)
        with open(fpath) as f:
           contents = f.read().strip()
        with open(fpath, "w") as f:
           f.write(contents.replace(d[files], ""))
```

```
$ python3.6 script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 15, in <module>
    f.write(contents.replace(d[files], ""))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: You need to mention ```f``` outside the ```' ' ``` or ```" "```. It should be ```f"/home/user/excel/report/{file}.txt", "r"```

Comment: Yes tried that getting -` File "script.py", line 6
    with open(f"/home/user/excel/report/{file}.txt", "r") as f:
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: `Python 2.7.17` and using Ubuntu-18.04

Comment: ```f-strings``` work on Python 3.6 and above

Comment: Then ```f-strings``` won't work

Comment: ```/home/user/excel/report/",file,".txt```

Comment: I would rather suggest `"/home/user/excel/report/" + file + ".txt"` or `"/home/user/excel/report/{file}.txt".format(file=file)`.

Comment: Ok, i have `text files` under this `/home/user/excel/report/` directory and its inside sub-directories as well.

Comment: Now installed `Python 3.6.9` and now `with open(f"/home/user/excel/report/{file}.txt", "r") as f:`  it is not looking recursively getting following error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 6, in <module>
    with open(f"/home/user/excel/report/{file}.txt", "r") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/excel/report/Abde_mdke.txt'

Comment: We need a bit more information about the data you have. I can see two somewhat reasonable ways to organize this, with the first one being `data.xlsx` containing relative paths (i.e. `file-001.txt` will be in `/home/.../reports/file-001.txt`, `subdir/file-002.txt` will be in `home/.../reports/subdir/file-002.txt`) and the second one being `data.xlsx` containing filenames only and you needing to snoop around

Comment: Yes correct. my `data.xlsx` file one of the column `D`  is having matching text files(without file path) and in my Ubuntu server for example under i have text file like`/home/user/excel/report/file-001.txt & other file `/home/user/excel/report/project-1/file-002.txt`,  etc... above code need to run recursively find the `user-id` if exists need to be removed from `text file`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't *need* to do it with pure Python and you will stay on your machine, the easiest way to find stuff recursively on a Linux distribution is using the `find` command. You can use it from python to get a list of files like this (tested in Python 3.8, your mileage may vary with the `subprocess` API as I think they changed some functions):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output('find .vim -name "async.vim"', shell=True).split()
[b'.vim/plugged/async.vim', b'.vim/plugged/async.vim/plugin/async.vim']
```

You can just grab the first matching file of the list and operate on that (or do it on all matching files, if you see fit):

```
import subprocess
# your pandas stuff here
for file in d:
    find_cmd = 'find /home/user/excel/reports -name "{0}"'.format(file)
    full_path = subprocess.check_output(find_cmd, shell=True).split()[0]
    # your replacement logic here
```

Security notice: `shell=True` is not good, it provides an entry point for arbitrary command execution. If you don't trust `data.xlsx` for any reason you should build the command up with a list the boring way.

Comment: Even `with open(f"{file}.txt", "r") as f:` failing with same error.

Comment: The `find` command found nothing and the list is empty. In your specific case this seems due to you having `find ... -name -name ...` which fails with error `find: paths must precede expression: ...`, but it is also possible your `data.xlsx` references files that just don't exist. You have to be the judge about your pipeline: is that file manually updated, or computer generated? Could you have accidentally deleted files in `.../reports`?

Comment: `data.xlsx` system generated file and all `text files` are present inside `/home/user/excel/report/` directory and its sub-directories.